# Can I select a value from different columns as one value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm not sure if I've phrased this question correctly, but I've never had a need to do something like this before.

I have 2 tables: `articles` and `article_content` that I want to search for a keyword.

Both tables have correlating columns, `ID` and `article_ID`, respectively.

`articles` contains the titles, and `article_content` contains the body and other meta.

I'm trying to do a keyword search that searches the title and the body content, but since they're in two different tables, I'm not sure how to return the ID if either table has a match.

Is it possible to do something like this in MySQL? Here's kind of what I'm thinking, this is obviously not valid code:

```
SELECT `ID` FROM `articles` OR `article_ID` from `article_content`
WHERE
    EITHER
        `articles`.`title` LIKE '%SearchTerm%' OR
        `article_content`.`description` LIKE '%SearchTerm%'
```

I'm trying to run this as one query, because I have an `ORDER BY CASE...` that weights the results.

I've been Googling, but I don't know what this would even be called so I'm stuck. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: i don't get what you want as result, both if existent= also make a [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 'article' source, `ID` 
FROM `articles` 
WHERE `title` LIKE '%SearchTerm%'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'content', `article_ID` 
FROM `article_content`
WHERE `description` LIKE '%SearchTerm%'
```

If you are not interested in the info where the term is found then

```
SELECT `ID` 
FROM `articles` 
WHERE `title` LIKE '%SearchTerm%'
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT `article_ID` 
FROM `article_content`
WHERE `description` LIKE '%SearchTerm%'
```

Comment: ooh, I like this. Let me give it a go.

Comment: I went with a slightly modified version of this one because it returns results much faster than the other answer. Thank you both!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.id
FROM   articles a,
       article_content ac
WHERE  a.title LIKE '%SearchTerm%'
        OR ac.description LIKE '%SearchTerm%';
```

You don't need to select both articles.ID and article_content. article_ID as both of them will be the same.

Comment: this is likely to do a cartesian product of the tables, which will be very inefficient